# Chaining rules that depend on each other

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I am using [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com) in my project.
In my ViewModel I have a property that is of type string, valid values are only string representing positive integers.
So, I created a simple `IntegerValidator` that checks whether or not the string can be parsed into an integer. This works.
Problem is, how to add the rule that it must be a positive integer? I would like to use the existing [Greater Than Validator](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#GreaterThan), but chaining it to the rule for my string property would compare it as a `string`, not as a parsed `int`. How to achieve this?

Sample of what I would like to do (note the `ToInt()`):

```
RuleFor(x => x.BatchNumber).SetValidator(new IntegerValidator())
                           .ToInt().GreaterThan(0);
```

Comment: This really makes sense! However, I wonder what the role of ToInt should be. As I see it, it should convert a `RuleBuilder<X, string>` into a `RuleBuilder<X, int>` and make sure that the validated value is converted to `int` at validation time. But... the method chain should return a `RuleBuilder<X, string>`. Right? So, there must be a way to instruct consecutive `int` rules (like `GreaterThan`) to do an `int` validation, but return a `string` rulebuilder. I fear this is beyond the current capabilities of FluentValidation.

Comment: @GertArnold: Well, the `ToInt` doesn't make too much sense, I think. I actually don't care *how* it is going to work, just *that* I can use `GreaterThan` and that an int is passed to `GreaterThan`.

Comment: Ok, my main point is that in the current mindset of Fluent Validation it may be conceptual problem.

Comment: Maybe create an IntegerValidator replacement that includes optional min and max parameters?  I use something similar (not with Fluent Validation, albeit) and use nullable ints for the bounds, so that upper and lower bounds can be set independently or disabled entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a custom method...

```
RuleFor(x=>x.BatchNumber).Must(BeAPositiveIntegerString);

private bool BeAPositiveIntegerString(string batchNumber)
{
    // check both parse ability and greater than (once parsed)
}
```

Less reusability but would work...

Comment: Sure, I can do that, without question. But that's exactly what I want to avoid and why I asked in the first place :)

Comment: I can find no way to cast a `RuleBuilder<T, string>` to a `RuleBuilder<T, int>`. The hierarchy of those classes require a deep change in FluentValidator's code, but one I'd mention to them; I can see similar use cases. In this particular case (to give you another non-answer), you could always chain a validator that checks for a negative sign in the string. ;)